# The form cannot be submitted beacuse of an error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, error, workflow-activity

I am using SP2010 with infopath 2010.
i've designed a custom approval which contains one approval process. this workflow prompts users to fill in reviewer, CC and comments on the workflow initialization form. this form has 2 people picker field one for reviewer and one for CC and both are enabled to accept multiple values.

The problem i am having is when i add user to reviewer and CC people picker control and click on start to start the workflow it's showing me "The form cannot be submitted beacuse of an error" error. If i leave the CC field blank the workflow runs fine. As far as i know i haven't changed anything on the server (production). Production server is SP Server 2010 without any SP1 installation.

IIS long error on production server:

> Event: 5374
>   Source: inforpath forms services 
>   Task category: Runtime - Business Logic
>   Error: There was a form postback error. (User: 0#.w|username, Form Name: Template, IP: , Request:SiteURL/_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={aac38048-177c-48b5-9bd1-87f888bf9541}&ID=172&TemplateID={383e9f7c-b111-4daa-979d-7b06c1459efb}&Source=http://Site URL /Forms/Main%2520Overview.aspx, Form ID: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:workflowInitAssoc:-AutoGen-2012-07-19T10:25:12:594Z, Type: SchemaValidationException, Exception Message: Schema validation found non-datatype errors.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is now fixed. Came through below article on internet which seems to have fixed my problem. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/a3c27dd4-baca-4ca6-a27c-82f2706bc9dc

Comment: Please put your comment as answer. Your question without answer is disorienting the ppl who want to answer or seek answers seeing in the list of questions this q with 0 answers

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same issue and I had the SP1 for SharePoint Designer2010 already installed.

SP D2010 Version : 14.0.6123.5001 (32-bit) with SP1

The issue :

---

I am using SP2010 with infopath 2010. i've designed a custom approval which contains one approval process. this workflow prompts users to fill in reviewer, CC and comments on the workflow initialization form. this form has 2 people picker field one for reviewer and one for CC and both are enabled to accept multiple values.

The problem i am having is when i add user to reviewer and CC people picker control and click on start to start the workflow it's showing me "The form cannot be submitted beacuse of an error" error. If i leave the CC field blank the workflow runs fine.

---

So, as I said, the SP1 is installed and that didn't solve the issue.

As suggested, I've tried to delete the InfoPath document (.xsn) and republish the workflow in order to get the .xsn regenerated but it did not solve my issue.

Finaly, I solved the issue doing the following steps :

1) In SharePoint Designer, go to All File and get to the concerned workflow

2) Open and edit its .xoml.wconfig.xml file (the config file)

3) Scrool down in order to get to the Approvers section :

4) Delete **xsi:nil="true"** in the *Approvers* and *CC* feilds (see code below):

```
    <d:Approvers >
        <d:Assignment >
            <d:Assignee/>
            <d:Stage xsi:nil="true"/>
            <d:AssignmentType>Serial</d:AssignmentType>
        </d:Assignment >
    </d:Approvers xsi:nil="true">                 <!-- instead it must be </d:Approvers> -->
    <d:ExpandGroups>true</d:ExpandGroups>
    <d:NotificationMessage/>
    <d:DueDateforAllTasks xsi:nil="true"/>
    <d:DurationforSerialTasks xsi:nil="true"/>
    <d:DurationUnits>Day</d:DurationUnits>
    <d:CC xsi:nil="true"/>                         <!-- instead it must be <d:CC/> -->
    <d:CancelonRejection>false</d:CancelonRejection>
    <d:CancelonChange>false</d:CancelonChange>
    <d:EnableContentApproval>false</d:EnableContentApproval>
```

5) Save (ctrl+s), close SharePoint Designer, reopen it and publish the workflow.

6) You can now retest the workflow startup from SharePoint and wish not to get the error! ;)

It worked for me.
I hope this has been helpfull to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

The author of this question answered it in comment to the original question by:

> This is now fixed. Came through below article on internet which seems
>   to have fixed my problem
>   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/a3c27dd4-baca-4ca6-a27c-82f2706bc9dc

I couldn't find any answer in the mentioned reference but after reading a dozen of enclosed references and subreferences (links and sublinks) made me to believe that the only given answer was in a sub-sub-link (sub-sub-reference), 2 hops away from the mentioned discussion:

- [I had this exact problem, checked it on several different environments and in the end it turned out that if I did my customizations from the 64bit version of SharePoint Designer it all worked well](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/a3c27dd4-baca-4ca6-a27c-82f2706bc9dc/#c8732ad4-fccb-44c2-8d35-819304a6f8d5).